# How to compare Strings with different encodings in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am running into a following situation where I am comparing two values that are identical yet the SQL Server doesn't think so. One is a value stored in DB and the other is a value imported into DB from a Flat File.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN 'Capital Markets - Americas' = 'Capital Markets – Americas' 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
    END
```

returns 0.

Can you guys help how can I compare ignoring the encoding?

Comment: Looking at this the hyphen is not the same character code.  In the first string it is ascii 45, and in the other it's ascii 150.

Comment: Beat me to it :-) One was probably created by auto-correct in Word or Excel. I don't think encodings will help here.

Comment: That's what I was thinking - don't think it would make any difference at all.

Comment: How do I get them to be equal ? I need them to be equal.

Comment: They just aren't...you could perhaps use REPLACE after processing the data that comes in from the flat file?  e.g. REPLACE('Capital Markets - Americas',CHAR(45),CHAR(150)) - something like that.

Comment: @MatRichardson - that works. I agree those hyphens look different.

Comment: You might want to consider cleaning the data after import and using the standard hyphen every time...otherwise (depending on what you are doing with the data) you will need to remember to do the replace in every comparison query you do.

Comment: Try to cast as nvarchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several commenters have alluded to, you could standardise hyphens (for example replacing `En dash` characters (ASCII Code 150) with hypens (ASCII Code 45):

```
DECLARE @Value1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Value2 VARCHAR(50)

SET @Value1 = 'Capital Markets - Americas'
SET @Value2 = 'Capital Markets – Americas'

SELECT CASE WHEN @Value1 = @Value2 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS OriginalComparison,
       CASE WHEN REPLACE(@Value1,CHAR(150),CHAR(45)) = REPLACE(@Value2,CHAR(150),CHAR(45))
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS NewComparison
```

You may find other characters which differ between your two data sources and can just keep wrapping extra `REPLACE` calls around the fields to replace these too (or write a function to do all the sanitising for you).